# The default value for vm.dirty_background_ratio

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Wondering why the default value for "vm.dirty_background_ratio" from Linux Server (CentOS and Ubuntu) is set to 40. Is this just a recommendation for safety? Or is there any particular reason why?

If the total system memory is over 32Gb, 40% is just a lot to set free. I googled pretty much all over the place, but we could not find enough rationale to support the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old question; but the same answer applies now (2024) that did when this was asked.

Quite simply, the vm.dirty_background_ratio and vm.dirty_ratio values were present already when I started using Linux around 1994. Typical systems then had like 8MB RAM, a high end desktop may have had 64-128MB, and servers maybe 512MB-1GB (but also faster disks), the values were appropriate then.

Since then, in general the thoughts on not changing it were:

1. "Don't rock the boat".  They don't want to cause a performance regression for anyone.  (I do note, at some point they did eventually reduce these some; dirty_ratio is now 20% and dirty_background_ratio is 10%, half the previous values.  And added vm.dirty_ratio_bytes and vm.dirty_background_ratio_bytes since on high memory systems 1% is still too high.
2. They had problems deciding on good new values.  Some workloads recommend setting this to a very low value, if the I/O system is just not fast enough it's better to run the workload at a slower pace than have GBs of writes just build up over time.  Other workloads can have heavy writes but they are bursty; or generate temp files that are not used for long before they are deleted; a large enough value to hold a burst and write it out over time (or to hold temp files and not have to write anything at all if they're deleted quickly enough) gives massive speed increases.
3. It's usually not a problem.  On a desktop it just doesn't come up that often that someone is doing massive sustained writes to a slow device, and the writes that do happen flush after 30 seconds.  On server setups where they do expect that to happen generally both the Linux vendor and vendor of database software, VM software, etc., will have a tuning guide that recommends adjusting values like this anyway.